# pasando checkbox .net mvc

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

tengo uno `checkbox` que estoy pasando por `post` hacia un controlador, pero cuando veo el resultado me llega el array vacio. Revise en el insepctor de elementos y si esta definiendo el `value`, alguna sugerencia??

Vista

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Usuario/", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formCollection" }))
{
    <table class="table-resumida">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Empresa</th>
                <th> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var data in ViewBag.dataRoles)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label> @Html.Raw(data["DETALLE"])  </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBox("idRol[]", new { Value = data["ID"] })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar Datos</button>
  }
```

Controlador

```
[HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeByRol]
    [MenuFilter]
    public ActionResult Usuario( FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var check = formCollection;



        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Entiendo que estás tratando de asignarle al valor del checkbox lo que obtienes de data["ID"]. Creo que el problema deriva que un Checkbox solo acepta como valor un boolean, mientras que data["ID"] estoy casi seguro que contiene un Int32

Comment: Y viste el valor de `formControl["idRol[]"]` en el controlador? Al enviar un `FormControl` por POST, la clase se carga con todos los `input` que tenga tu form en la vista, te vendría bien poner un breakpoint en esa función al hacer debug.